# Flutter video player 0.10.9+2 cannot be initialized in real Android project

Tags: flutter, video-player

Following the latest instruction of [video_player V0.10.9](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), I got very strange situation, for the [same video url](https://captnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/demo_video_02.mp4), it works on a brand new flutter project just for demo, but doesn't work in my real project, I mean I got initialization issue in my real **Android** project. And I've already double checked configurations of the both projects, all are the same.

**Both projects works on iPhone, and demo project works on Android phone, but real project doesn't work on the same Android phone.**

I put following reference to both pubspec.yaml file:

```
video_player: ">=0.10.9+2 <2.0.0"
```

In my demo project, it works correctly:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final videoUrl =
      'https://captnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/demo_video_02.mp4';

  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print('^_^initState()');

    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {
          videoPlayerController.play();
          print('^_^play()');
        });
      })
      ..addListener(() {
        print('Is playing: ${videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying}');
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: videoPlayerController.value.initialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController))
            : Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But in my real project, initialize() will always make **MissingPluginException** twice, one for method name `init` on channel `flutter.io/videoPlayer` and one for method name `create` on channel `flutter.io/videoPlayer`. This exception is thrown at line 319 in file `platform_channel.dart`.

```dart
void initVideoPlayer() {
  if (TextUtil.isEmpty(videoUrl)) {
    logger.debug('videoUrl is EMPTY.');
    return;
  }

  logger.debug('videoUrl: $videoUrl');

  videoPlayerController?.dispose();
  videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl)
    ..initialize()
    ..addListener(() {
      // logger.debug(
      //     'isVideoPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying: ${videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying}');

      if (isVideoPreparing && videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
        isVideoPreparing = false;
        isVideoPlaying = true;
      } else if (isVideoPlaying && !videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying) {
        videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration(milliseconds: 0));
        isVideoPlaying = false;
        stopVideo();
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I double checked, configurations of both projects are all the same including iOS and Android settings, absolutely follow every steps in official instruction.

I even thought if multidex makes this difference, but the demo project still works correctly after I set it to support multidex.

Any help would be very appreciated!

BTW, my flutter environment is on stable channel and healthy.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-CN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Volumes/Transcend/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Volumes/Transcend/Development/AndroidSDK
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM G9500 • 988a1b474239545746 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Try force restarting the app. It'll work I guess.

Comment: @VinothVino, I tried, and I even restarted my phone multiple times, but still does matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing `flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0` from *pubspec.yaml*.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to flutter version 1.20.4 and the video_player plugin will work fine. Its the new flutter version that creates issue with video_player plugin

Update:
current flutter sdk stable version & video_player plugin latest version works fine